Overload std::to_string for user-defined types?
What does the C++ standard have to say about overloading/implementing a templatized version of std::to_string like so:
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <ostream>

namespace std {
  template<typename T>
  string to_string(const T& in)
  {
     ostringstream oss;
     oss << in;
     return oss.str();
  }
}

Is this expressedly disallowed?  Or cause nasal-daemons to fly out of the nose?
g++ accepts the above code with --std=c++11 -Wextra -pedantic-errors, reports no errors, and the executable generates the output that I expect (which, of course, does not mean anything in context to my question)

unless an exception says otherwise you cannot add to std::

why do you not do it the other way around. You can write your own function template, that calls std::to_string when possible and falls back to your implementation otherwise. There is no issue with that

Don't add things to namespace std. See Should you overload swap in the std namespace?

"...It is undefined behavior to add declarations or definitions to namespace std or to any namespace nested within std, with a few exceptions noted below...." https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std

If you put your custom types in a namespace, then you can add a to_string function in that namespace that takes the specific classes as arguments. Then the compiler can use argument-dependent lookup to find the function if you just call it as to_string(object_of_namespace_class).

What you should not do (besides adding things to the std namespace) is to use a generic template "god" function which attempts to handle all cases (including cases that are already handled by other overloads or specializations). That will only lead to confusing problems in the future.

Proposed code is not only UB, but also will compete with already existing overloads of std::to_string.
